# with recursion in python calculate the amount of letters strings s and t share

Tags: python, recursion, list-comprehension

I have to recursively or with list comprehension calculate the *lingo* score of two given strings. There is one point for ever letter that the two strings share.

I tried doing this, but it only works if s[0] is in t but otherwise it doesn't do what it is supposed to and I cannot see what is actually going wrong here.

```py
def count(e, L):
    lc = [1 for x in L if x == e]
    return sum(lc)

def lingo(s, t):
    if s == '' or t == '':
        return 0
    elif s == t:
        return len(s)
    if s[0] in t:
        lc = [count(s[x], t) for x in range(len(t))]
        return sum(lc)
    else:
        #remove s[0] and try again
        lingo(s[:1], t)
```

these assertions are with the assignment:

```py
assert lingo('diner', 'proza') == 1
assert lingo('beeft', 'euvel') == 2
assert lingo('gattaca', 'aggtccaggcgc') == 5
assert lingo('gattaca', '') == 0
```

Comment: You are missing the keyword `return` on the last line. It should be `return lingo(s[:1], t)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The most obvious mistake

You are missing a `return` statement on the last line of your code. Instead of:

```py
    else:
        #remove s[0] and try again
        lingo(s[:1], t)
```

it should be:

```py
    else:
        #remove s[0] and try again
        return lingo(s[:1], t)
```

### A redundancy in your code

The following piece of your code is unnecessary:

```py
    elif s == t:
        return len(s)
```

Although this returns the correct result, it is a special case and doesn't particularly help the general case. In most cases `s` and `t` will be different; and the logic to calculate their amount of shared letters should work also when they are equal.

### A mistake in the algorithm logic

This line of your code is highly suspicious:

```py
lc = [count(s[x], t) for x in range(len(t))]
```

First of all, `x` is in range of the length of `t`, but is used as an index for `s`. If `t` is longer than `s`, this will immediately raise an `IndexError` exception. If `t` is shorter than or same length as `s`, then it will not raise an exception, but will most likely return the wrong result.

Note this interesting test case that was provided:

```
assert lingo('beeft', 'euvel') == 2
```

The letter `'e'` appears twice in `'beeft'` and twice in `'euvel'`, and the result is 2. Yet if you calculate `count(s[1], t) + count(s[2], t)` you will find the value 4. This is because the first `'e'` of `s` is found twice in `t`, and the second `'e'` of `s` is also found twice in `t`.

[Janecx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64247143/with-recursion-in-python-calculate-the-amount-of-letters-strings-s-and-t-share/64248011#64248011) provides one way to carefully fix this. You need to understand the logic behind `min(s.count(s[0]), t.count(s[0]))`.

### Other python solutions

Right now you absolutely want to use recursion and list comprehensions. In case you are interested in other ways to solve your problem, here are different algorithms.

**Sorting the strings** (sorting is a powerful tool that makes many problems easy)

```py
def lingo(s, t):
  s = sorted(s) # this doesn't modify the original string, it makes a local copy
  t = sorted(t) # this doesn't modify the original string, it makes a local copy
  result = 0
  i = 0
  j = 0
  while (i < len(s) and j < len(t)):
    if s[i] == t[j]:
      result += 1
      i += 1
      j += 1
    elif s[i] < t[j]:
      i += 1
    else:
      j += 1
  return result
```

*Complexity analysis: sorting takes `N log N + M log M` operations, where N=len(s) and M=len(t). The whole while loop only takes N + M operations; it is that fast because s and t are sorted in the same order, so we reach an element of s as the same time as the corresponding element in t, so we don't need to compare every element of s against every element of t.*

**collections.Counter** (a python object specifically designed for counting occurrences)

```py
import collections
def lingo(s, t):
  return sum((collections.Counter(s) & collections.Counter(t)).values())
```

*Complexity analysis: this takes `N + M` operations, where N=len(s) and M=len(t). Counter simply counts the number of occurrences of each letter in s by going through s once, and the number of occurrences of each letter in t by going through t once; then the `&` operation keeps the minimum of the two counts for each letter (reminiscent of Janecx's `min(...)` operation); then all the counts are summed up. Summing up only takes as many operations as there are distinct letters, which in the case of a DNA sequence is 4; in the case of an alphabetical word is 26; and in general in a ASCII/Latin-1 string is at most 256.*

**Recursive approach** from [Janecx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64247143/with-recursion-in-python-calculate-the-amount-of-letters-strings-s-and-t-share/64248011#64248011) *Complexity analysis: takes `N * M` operations, where N=len(s) and M=len(t). This is much slower than the other two approaches, because for every element of s we need to go through every element of t; written iteratively, this would be a for loop nested inside a second for loop.*

Answer (score 0):

There you go. What this code does? If one of the string is empty, return 0. In the other cases, it finds the minimal number of occurences of s[0] in s and t, and then we use recursion to calculate the minimal number of occurences of s[1] in the version of t without the first character, and so on.

```py
def lingo(s, t):
    if s == '' or t == '':
        return 0
    return min(s.count(s[0]), t.count(s[0])) + lingo(s[1:], t.replace(s[0], ''))


assert lingo('diner', 'proza') == 1
assert lingo('beeft', 'euvel') == 2
assert lingo('gattaca', 'aggtccaggcgc') == 5
assert lingo('gattaca', '') == 0
```